# How to build dual core MCU project with a single keypress (or click) in eclipse (SMT32cubeIDE)?

Tags: eclipse, project-management

The picture below shows a dual core (Arm CM4 and CM7) project in STM32cubeIDE (Eclipse based). I assigned F4 to "build project" so I can click each #2 and #3 and press F4 to build the individual projects. Pressing F4 on #1 does nothing though. The righ-click menu for #1 does not show "Build project" like it does for #2 and #3.

Is there a macro or something that I can do to build #2 and #3 by highlighting #1 and pressing F4 or a mouse click? Thanks.

[image: stm32cubeide project picture]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about electronics design

Comment: STM32s and embedded design are covered at EE.SE